# BigQuery: Using LAST_VALUE() to skip values other than just NULLs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Understood that we can use the LAST_VALUE() function to skip NULL values in BigQuery.

Using the "Channel" here as our example, i.e.
LAST_VALUE(**Channel**) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)

However, says if there is a value "ATM" (so not NULL) in the Channel that I also want to skip, is it possible to use the LAST_VALUE() function here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, [LAST_VALUE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#last_value) supports *IGNORE NULLS*. Therefore you can acheive your goal like this.

```sql
SELECT LAST_VALUE(IF(Channel = 'ATM', NULL, Channel) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY event_timestamp ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  FROM `your_table`;
```

Comment: Nice neat clean answer! Thanks @jaytiger!